# up-to-date info on cocos2d-js/html5 touch, keyboard, mouse events -tutorials

Tags: html, animation, touch, keyboard-events, cocos2d-js

Anyone seen a tutorial or examples (more recent) dealing with touch and mouse events in cocos2D-js and html5 ?  The other problem I have is I have a game (well the makings of a game) that deals with users pushing buttons that set off small, short animations - nothing to do with flying, collisions, running, etc. Hard to find those kinds of examples, controlling multiple animations...
What's the best thing to use too? Cocos Console?

Answer (score 0):

here is some resources on examples :

1 - http://cocos2d-x.org/js-tests/

2 - http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/Cocos2D-HTML-5-Tutorial-Series-table-of-contents.aspx